# Finding fields in String java regular expression

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, expression

I am not good at Java regular expressions.

I have following text

```
[[image:testimage.png||height=\"481\" width=\"816\"]]
```

I want to extract image: , height and width from above text. Could someone help me writing regular expression to achieve it ?

Comment: A good tool for trial and error: [Regexp Editor](http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html)

Comment: Another good tool is [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/)

Comment: You have something missing at the end of question...  "I have n"  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
((?:image|height|width)\D+?([a-zA-Z\d\.\\"]+))
```

You will get two groups.

e.g.,

> 1. height=\"481\"
> 2. 481

Answer (score 1):

If this is your exact String

```
[[image:testimage.png||height=\"481\" width=\"816\"]]
```

Then try the following (Crude):

```
String input = // read your input string
String regex = ".*height=\\\\\"(\\d+)\\\\\" width=\\\\\"(\\d+)"
String result = input.replaceAll(regex, "$1 $2");
String[] height_width = result.split(" ")
```

Thats one way of doing it, another (better) would be to use a [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match a property and its associated value. You will have to iterate through every match it finds in your source string to get all the information you want.

```
(\w+)[:=]("?)([\w.]+)\2
```

You have three capture groups. Two of which you are interested in:

- Group 1: The name of the property. (image, height, width...)
- Group 3: The value of the property.

Here is a breakdown of the regex:

```
(\w+)       #Group 1: Match the property name.
[:=]        #The property name/value separator.
("?)        #Group 2: The string delimiter.
([\w.]+)    #Group 3: The property value. (Accepts letters, numbers, underscores and periods)
\2          #The closing string delimiter if there was one.
```